# How to determine if OSX is on battery and not in power

Tags: macos, cocoa, battery

I would like to adjust functionality of my app when in battery mode

**How to detect for an application it is in battery mode, etc. when the mode changes?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`IOPSGetTimeRemainingEstimate` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOPowerSources_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/IOPSGetTimeRemainingEstimate) returns amount of remaining power.

Cited from the *discussion* section:

> If attached to an "Unlimited" power source, like AC power or any
>   external source, the return value is kIOPSTimeRemainingUnlimited
>
> If the system is on "Limited" power, like a battery or UPS, but is
>   still calculating the time remaining, which may take several seconds
>   after each system power event (e.g. waking from sleep, or unplugging
>   AC Power), the return value is kIOPSTimeRemainingUnknown
>
> Otherwise, if the system is on "Limited" power and the system has an
>   accurate time remaining estimate, the system returns a CFTimeInterval
>   estimate of the time remaining until the system is out of battery
>   power.
>
> If you require more detailed battery information, use
>   IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo> and IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription>.

---

[`IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOPowerSources_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource) can be used to register a callback function on power source related events.